# VideoView disappears

Tags: android, android-videoview, mp4

I have a layout contains **Title**, **(VideoView, ProgressBar, ImageView)**, **Description** .
This layout is a list item layout . I want to play video from URL when user clicks the image, which is a thumbanil for the video , so I did that inside getView() inside ListAdapter

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onClick...");
                    try {
                        VideoView videoView = (VideoView) convertView2
                                .findViewById(R.id.post_media_video);

                        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PostsFragment.this.getActivity());
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                        Uri video = Uri.parse(post.getUrlString());
                        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                        Log.i(TAG, "start video ...");
                        videoView.requestFocus();
                        videoView.start();
                        image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

but the problem is, when the user clicks the image, VideoView disappear, as if it is visibilitye is GONE .
What mistake did I make ? I searched if the ListView is the trouble maker , but others can dispaly the video ...

My Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >




       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/item_vid_title"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Title"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:layout_gravity="right" />

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_margin="5dp" >

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/post_media_image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:visibility="visible" />

           <ProgressBar
               android:id="@+id/post_media_progress"
               android:layout_width="72dp"
               android:layout_height="72dp"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

           <VideoView
           android:id="@+id/post_media_video"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:visibility="gone" />

       </RelativeLayout>

      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/item_vid_description"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Description"
           android:layout_gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your ImageView is the one that is visible and you set it to gone.
There doesn't seem to be an instance where your videoview visibility is set to visible.  Perhaps this is done in code not shown, but you wouldn't see a video since the layout initializes it to gone.

Comment: indeed i did set it to visible . but I initialized other views in layout as gone , then in code i set them to visible and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

```
videoView.setVisibility(View.Visible)
```

This may solve your problem